# How can I perform copy/move file operations while ensuring data integrity?

Tags: windows-7, nas, file-transfer

I've got a huge amount of family photos stored on a NAS drive that I would like to move to my Windows computer, edit, and then move back for archival purposes.

However, I'm a bit paranoid about data integrity. What I would like to do is use a program (preferably well known) that verifies data integrity after I complete the file operations, to ensure nothing is lost or corrupted during this process.

Can someone suggest a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Best tool for this job is [`rsync`](http://rsync.samba.org/). It can quickly sync deep directory trees and ensure that data is transmitted safely.

Many NAS boxes support `rsync` protocol natively. If your NAS does, you're in luck.

If you use Linux as your client, most likely you already have `rsync` installed. To copy content from NAS to your computer, use this command line:

```
rsync -av user@host:/some/dir/ /some/local/dir/
```

If you want to 100% ensure that data was copied safely, add `--checksum` option - but it will make copy a bit slower.

On Windows, you could install [`grsync`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/grsync-win/) - it has nice GUI, but it also installs command line `rsync` Windows executable, which you could use with exact same command line as used above for Linux.

Also, you can copy data back to NAS using this syntax (swap source and target):

```
rsync -av /some/local/dir/ user@host:/some/dir/
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want something with a GUI, then [Teracopy](http://codesector.com/teracopy) is where you want to go, taking advantage of the "Always test after copy" option.

If you're happy on the command line then [Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) is where I'd start (and whilst you're there, look up the "Verify" command).

Answer (score 0):

If you do this on a routinely basis, then you should probably look into a specialized copier tool that automates these steps, but if it's just one-time thing, then you should simply divorce copying and integrity verification steps.

Get one of the checksum verifier utilities, e.g. [Microsoft's own](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533), run it against files on the NAS, save the checksums, copy file over, compute the checksums and compare them to the originals. Then do your edits. Then compute the checksums, copy files back to NAS, computer their checksums and verify them again.