# Windows 8 safe file copy?

Tags: windows-8, file-transfer

Does Windows 8 64-bit copy files safely in the explorer (safe = write + verify the write) between folders?  If not, is there a built-in or 3rd party tool that can?  I want to leave no doubt that the files were transferred successfully before I delete the originals.

Comment: The `copy` command includes a switch (`/v`) that verifies, so if you use the command-prompt, you can use that. To be extra safe, you could use a simple batch file: `copy /v %1 %2 %3 %4   &   fc /b %1 %2`. Of course drive caches might cause inaccurate results…

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I perform copy/move file operations while ensuring data integrity?](http://superuser.com/questions/665161/how-can-i-perform-copy-move-file-operations-while-ensuring-data-integrity)

Comment: You already asked this in another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [TaraCopy](http://www.filehippo.com/download_teracopy/) does what I'm asking for: verifying files (using a CRC check) after they've been copied.

Comment: It's 'TeraCopy'.